# How to host my existing website with Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, hosting

Google has given me 15GB of storage. Can I host my own website having my own domain?

Comment: The the question is about using a web application, it's use is for sor a task that is out of the scope ot this site. Creating / managing website questions might be asked in [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, can I host my own website which having my own domain?

No.

> Also can I install WordPress to my website if that can be hosted with Google Drive?

No, that's not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Hosting web pages with Google Drive has not been available since August 31, 2016.

#### References

- [Host web pages with Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en)
- [Deprecating web hosting support in Google Drive](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html)
- [Reminder: Turn down of Google Drive web hosting coming soon](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2016/07/reminder-turn-down-of-google-drive-web.html)